# How can words with misspellings be corrected in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame and I want the wrong words to be edited in it. First i delete the characters that have been repeated more than twice in a word and then i apply Spell Correction on it. For the first part, I can only apply changes on strings. I want to be able to apply it to the data frame as well. How can I do this?

```
text='Aye concreeete steel and plastic housesss will keep us alll safe and flourishing ?'


import re
def reduce_lengthening(text):
        pattern = re.compile(r"(.)\1{2,}")
        return pattern.sub(r"\1\1", text)
    

print('string is: ',reduce_lengthening(text))
```

out put string is:

`Aye concreete steel and plastic housess will keep us all safe and flourishing ?`

How can I apply this function to the following data frame?

```
text=['dear pados wali anttty , can  just keep your thoughts and nose out  business raising_hands  thaaaank .',
'but  least  did not call him losers  suckers ,  juuust was did not want   the cemetery and honor them ,  big deal.',
'some hunters are just entitled , you are lucky  have them.',
'thin corrrect time that.. only one person could save  from this crisis  ..   correct sarthak ? ?',
'thereee  also the wuhan virus.   that totally different ?',
'does nooot every woman hav  adam apple amp;  flat hairy chest ?']
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['Text']=text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have do it with `apply` function like below

```
df["Text"] = df["Text"].apply(reduce_lengthening)
```

or before adding this column ( `using` df['Text']=text`),you can pass each text element to` reduce_lengthening` in list comprehension like this, and store the resulting list

```
df["Text"] = [reduce_lengthening(x) for x in text]
```